# Adding integer values from a radio form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to create a checklist that provides a total number of points based on the value of the radio button selection (with jquery). The score for each input varies.

I can get the individual values but not sure how to add them up?

```js
/* jquery */

$(document).ready(function(){

  function setScore() {
    var score = $('input:checked').val();
    $('#score').text(score);
  }

    // set score on input change
  $('input').change(setScore);

    // set score on initialization
  setScore();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>Facebook link?</label>
  <input type="radio"  class="radio" name="Facebook" value="4">Yes</input>
</li>

<li>
  <label>Instagram link?</label>
  <input type="radio"  class="radio" name="Instagram" value="6">Yes</input>
</li>

<span>Score: <span id="score"></span></span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `radio` button input type should be same name. Otherwise it will select all `radio`. And you should use different value for each `radio` button.

Comment: `:radio:checked` is a better selector for this than `input:checked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `setScore` function to:

```
function setScore() {
    var score = 0;
    $.each($('input:checked'), function (i,input) { score += Number( input.value);});
    $('#score').text(score);
}
```

(Assuming there are no checkbox inputs that need to be excluded)

---

To add values for checked Facebook and Instagram buttons only, the  `'input:checked'` selector can be made more specific, as for example:

```
':checked[name="Facebook"], :checked[name="Instagram"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can just try this way**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function setTotalScore() {
    var score = 0;
    $('.radio').each(function(val,data){
        score+=parseInt(data.value.split('-')[1]);
    });
    $('#totalScore').text(score);
  }
  function setScore() {
    var score = $('input:checked').val();
    $('#score').text(score);
  }
  $('input').change(setScore);
  setTotalScore();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>Facebook link?
      <input type="radio"  class="radio" name="social" value="Facebook-4">Yes</input>
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label>Instagram link?
      <input type="radio"  class="radio" name="social" value="Instagram-6">Yes</input>
  </label>
</li>
<p><strong>Individual Score:</strong> <span id="score"></p>
<p><strong>Total Score:</strong> <span id="totalScore"></p>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not seeing a change here?

Comment: ah no sorry didn't know about that.

Comment: Ahh! Okay! :) @JPB

Comment: I Updated my answer. You can click to see the result @JPB